# Simplify server setup from base image configuration

Tags: server, configuration

I have to configure 10 -20 servers every year starting from the same base image. However each server is set up with its own customer specific passwords and program licenses. Because of this I usually have to uninstall and reinstall each piece of software so I can set it up again with a new password and license. This unfortunately causes me to have to re-import and reconfigure non customer specific items just because the application was reinstalled. Is there a way to simplify entering all the customer specific information/licenses so the applications do not need to be reinstalled?

Details: setting up a Dell R540 with programs like McAfee that require customer specific information as well as generic policies to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could automate the entire process (installing/reinstalling, entering information and configuration settings) using PowerShell. It would have a large time investment, but it would be worth it in the long run. I am currently using PowerShell to automate creation of Virtual Machines and downloading software (visual studio, chrome, notepad++ etc.) onto them to create a machine for development purposes.

Comment: This is helpful. I did not realize PowerShell had that kind of power

Comment: @IllusionsMichael depending on what software you need to download, [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) may help simplify the process